# Display multiselect checkboxes inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to display these multiselect checkboxes inline, without dropdown?
[Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

Comment: Why would you use that plugin if you aren't wanting it to show a dropdown? I'm sure there is a way to edit the css of the dropdown to make it inline(not recommended) but it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

NO

Because at the begining of the doc you given, it's clearly written :

> Bootstrap Multiselect is a JQuery based plugin to provide an intuitive
>   user interface for using select inputs with the multiple attribute
>   present. Instead of a select a bootstrap button will be shown as
>   dropdown menu containing the single options as checkboxes.

Extract : 
**will be shown as dropdown menu containing the single options as checkboxes**